# How do I solve the Java error:'The Method toLowerCase() is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>"

Tags: java, file, types, arraylist

I'm trying to populate a spinner with files in a specific directory with a specific file type(.dbf). Unfortunately I keep getting the error "The method toLowerCase() is undefined for the type ArrayList". How do I solve it?

```
public ArrayList<String> ReadDirectory(){
String path="./database";

File folder = new File(path);
File[] ListOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < ListOfFiles.length; i++){
    if (ListOfFiles[i].isFile()){
        files.add(ListOfFiles[i].getName());
        if (files.endsWith(".dbf") || files.endsWith(".DBF")){
            }
    }
}
return files;
        }


}
```

Error is given on this line:

```
if (files.endsWith(".dbf") || files.endsWith(".DBF")){
```

files is declared at the top of the script in the following way:

```
ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Where are you using it? I can't see it in your current code.

Comment: The part where the error is is not included in source above. Where do you declare `files`?

Comment: call it on the file name, not the array. you make the same mistake with `endsWith`.

Comment: Give the stack-trace and exact location of error. Post the other relevant code if any.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake with the posting:) Code should show properly now. I tried cleaning my project, didn't work.

Comment: @mtk There won't be a stacktrace for a compiler-error ;)

Answer (score 7):

> How do I solve the Java error: 'The Method toLowerCase() is undefined
>   for the type ArrayList'

I cant see you using `toLowerCase()` method in your posted code. however, i assume you are trying to call `toLowerCase()` on a list reference. List doesnt have `toLowerCase()` method. String has [`toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) method.

you probably ment to do this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println(list.get(0).toLowerCase()); //this is legal
System.out.println(list.toLowerCase()); //this isn't legal as there is no toLowerCase() method in list
```

Answer (score 0):

As i know toLowerCase() is defined only for string object,so take from ArrayList single string during iteration,change this string and replace old string in the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.endsWith()` on a File. Considering you are using a `for` loop, you should go for `files[i].endsWith()`. However, using an enhanced for, e.g. `for (File currentFile : files)` is a more common approach.

Same thing goes for the `.toLowerCase()` method.